# How do you omit fields in TypegraphQL

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

Let's say we have the following User model.
`{ id: ID, email: string, username: string }`

Then I want to define 2 queries:

1. Used by the owner to get their settings page so it contains sensitive information such as email (perhaps sin number)
2. Used by other users to search for a user (by username) & we do **NOT** want to expose the email or sin number
   I have been researching the documentation & cannot find how to accomplish this. I was thinking to grab the info for the fields manually & parse it per query but that seems like an oversight.

UPDATE:
Here is sort of what I am trying to do:

```
class User {
  @Field(
    () => ID
  )
  id: string;

  @Authorized("CURRENT_USER")
  @Field(
    {
      nullable: true
    }
  )
  email: string;

  @Field()
  username: string;
}
```

Resolver:

```
export default class UserResolver {
  @Authorized("CURRENT_USER")
  @Query(
    () => User
  )
  async user(@Arg('username', () => String) username: string) {
     // TODO: if username is current user then allow email
     // else do not allow email, (I need auth checker in here)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am considering making 2 models? 1 for public & one for private but that seems strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you should be able to use the Authorized decorator in TypegraphQL. With this solution you should be able to add it to the email field in your User model. This should also be able to work with the sid field as well

**Have a look here:** https://typegraphql.com/docs/authorization.html

For example your User model could look something like this:

```
class User {
  @Field()
  id: ID;

  @Authorized("LOGGEDINUSER")
  @Field({nullable: true})
  email: string;

  @Field()
  username: string;
}
```

**You will have to allow the email field to be nullable**

You will also need to define an authChecker, with this you can run your logic to check if the user is the owner of the data, therefore granting them access to the data.

An authChecker can look something like this:

```
export const customAuthChecker: AuthChecker<Context> = (
  { args, context, info, root },
  roles
) => {
  // roles is an array of string which contains the authorization required to access the current resource
  // this is specified in the @Authorized decorator
  if (roles.includes("LOGGEDINUSER")) {
    // here check if the user is actually logged in and if they are allowed to access the resource
    // return true if they are allowed to access the resource
  }
  return false;
};
```

You will also need to change your call to the buildSchema to include the custom authChecker and authMode.
For example:

```
  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [UserResolver],
    authChecker: customAuthChecker,
    authMode: "null",
  });
```

**Note** this will still return an email field but instead of returning the actual email it will return null when the user does not meet the authentication requirements

Comment: Awesome! One issue with this approach is that we cannot check if it's the owner that is making the query. It says Logged in User. Any idea's?

Comment: Well you could change it to be owner and then inside the auth checker you have access to the context. For example if you were using express session you would be able to tell who the user is and compare it to the data they are trying to receive in root variable.

Comment: Another option would be to just not select the email from database, and allow the username field to nullable in the type graphql model

Comment: If neither of these solutions work for you, you can send/show me more of your code as I may be able to help further

Comment: Sure, I can try to whip up a sample & post one later this week. Thanks Ethan!

Comment: I updated the post to show a more complete example :)! If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. What is the GraphQL way?

Comment: I would still use an auth checker to solve this problem. I have got a working example of it I can share. The only problem is you are trying to type cast an any type to a user object however you can still add certainty to the type conversion if you only use the `@Authorized("CURRENT_USER")` on the user model. Then inside the auth checker you can make a comparison between the user model and the logged in user to decide if they are the current user. If using express-session you are able to add the request object to the graphql context and can check authentication that way.

Comment: Yes that would be great! Thanks for the help Ethan! Could you please share the example please?

Comment: Here is the code [sandbox](https://shorturl.at/jsz78), hopefully it works. Have a look at the readme for a bit of a description

Comment: The link doesn't take me to a sandbox. It directs me to the homepage of the link shortener website. Can you please send me another link?

Comment: Yeh will do. The link is too long for the comment, I will try a different link shortener. That hopefully works. [Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/peaceful-feather-vp85ke)

Comment: I would love to chat with you about this more. Related question: is there a way to prevent sending the email data. For instance if I have an SQL query & fetch the data, I would like to not fetch the data if it will become null anyway. Wondering if there is an easy way to do that. I was thinking about using the Context.

Comment: Ethan, thanks for the help, I'd like to buy you a coffee or something. It was super helpful :)